# my Array List outputs in one line only?

Tags: java

I've added my whole code to clarify, my problem isn't that am missing a "println" like many thankfully suggested my problem in my code below I ask the user to enter monthly investment, yearly interest rate, and years I then ask them if they want to continue by adding another monthly investment, yearly interest rate, and years until they say no after which I want to display it. The problem is every time they say yes to entering more data it should display that date in the second line in so on one the program end or they say no to continuing, instead it just displays everything in one line.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class FutureValueApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // display a welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator");
    System.out.println();

    ArrayList<String> FutureValueArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(4);

    // perform 1 or more calculations
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {

        // get the input from the user
        System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
        double monthlyInvestment = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
        double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 30);
        int years = getIntWithinRange(sc,
            "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);

        // calculate the future value
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate/12/100;
        int months = years * 12;
        double futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
            monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

        // get the currency and percent formatters
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        percent.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

        // format the result as a single string
        String results =
              "Monthly investment:\t"
                  + currency.format(monthlyInvestment) + "\n"
            + "Yearly interest rate:\t"
                  + percent.format(interestRate/100) + "\n"
            + "Number of years:\t"
                  +  years + "\n"
            + "Future value:\t\t"
                  + currency.format(futureValue) + "\n";

        // print the results
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
        System.out.println(results);

      String monthlyInvestmentFormat = currency.format(monthlyInvestment);
      String interestRateFormat = percent.format(interestRate/100);
      String futureValueFormat = currency.format(futureValue);

      FutureValueArrayList.add(monthlyInvestmentFormat);
      FutureValueArrayList.add(interestRateFormat);
      FutureValueArrayList.add(Integer.toString(years));
      FutureValueArrayList.add(futureValueFormat);




        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();

        System.out.println();
    }

     System.out.print("Inv/Mo.\tRate\tYears\tFuture Value\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < FutureValueArrayList.size(); i++)
      {

         System.out.print(FutureValueArrayList + "\n");

      }

     System.out.println();
}

public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    boolean isValid = false;
    double d = 0;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextDouble())
        {
            d = sc.nextDouble();
            isValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
    }
    return d;
}

public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
double min, double max)
{
    double d = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
        if (d <= min)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        else if (d >= max)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        else
            isValid = true;
    }
    return d;
}

public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    boolean isValidInt = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (isValidInt == false)
    {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            isValidInt = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
        }
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
    }
    return i;
}

public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
int min, int max)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        i = getInt(sc, prompt);
        if (i <= min)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
        else if (i >= max)
            System.out.println(
                "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
        else
            isValid = true;
    }
    return i;
}

public static double calculateFutureValue(double monthlyInvestment,
double monthlyInterestRate, int months)
{
    double futureValue = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
    {
        futureValue =
            (futureValue + monthlyInvestment) *
            (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
    }
    return futureValue;
}
```

}

my for loop gives me an output like this the bold was when the user enter yes to entering more data it should be on the second line not together with the first time they entered the data:

> $100.00 2.0% 2 $2,450.64 **$150.00 2.0% 2 $36,420.71**

Comment: Are you trying to use `'\t'` for a newline?

Comment: no i've updated my post to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You where using `System.out.print()` which will print something one 1 line without the `\n` delimiter.

Use `System.out.println()` which will automatically put the `\n` delimiter at the end of your string.

**`\n` is a new line delimiter.**

**`\t` is a tab delimiter.**

**EDIT:** I think you are trying to label each output. (because of the first print statement)

If so you cannot use a for loop (technically). Mainly because the loop does not know which label goes to which element/index.

If you know which element will store which data just manually label them

> System.out.println("Rate: " + FutureValueArrayList.get(i))
>
> // i being the index at which the rate value is stored`

**EDIT:** with regards to your comment.

You will need to look into [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

**Sample Code** - this will print a table with 20 characters column width.

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    System.out.println(formatter.format("%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*", "Title*"));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        formatter = new Formatter();
        String rowData = "info" + i;
        System.out.println(formatter.format("%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s", rowData, rowData, rowData, rowData, rowData));
    }
```

Comment: Ive edited my question to clarify

Comment: I updated my answer I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `println()` to display each entry in a new line. It'll print your entry and then insert a line separator at end to terminate the line.

```
System.out.println(FutureValueArray);
```

Otherwise, you can modify your `print()` method parameters to make it print on new line. Something like this:-

```
System.out.print(FutureValueArray + "\n");
```

Note that `\t` represents the horizontal tab character whereas `\n` represents the new line character.

Comment: after they enter their their first values I ask them if they want to enter another values if they say yes i want to get from them and then output the first values they entered and then then second values they entered when they said yes to enter another values in seprate lines your suggestion still prints it all in one line?

Comment: I didn't get you! You want those to be printed in 1 line or not?

Comment: ya I updated my post with more clarity

Answer (score 1):

use

```
for (int i = 0; i < FutureValueArrayList.size(); i++)

      {

         String FutureValueArray = FutureValueArrayList.get(i);

         System.out.println(FutureValueArray + "\n");

      }
```

println automatically adds new line character  at the end

"/n" can also be used as new line character

Comment: I've updated my code to clarify